# Justification in Unicode

Tags: unicode, text-alignment, justify

I'm almost positive that Unicode has a recommendation for whether and when to add spacing around interpunctuation characters (like the raised dot, ·), but I can't seem to find it again. Can someone with better Unicode-fu help me?